# Find multiples of 3 or 5 below 10

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 below 10

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
result = 0
numbers.each do |number|
  if number % 3 == 0 or number % 5 == 0
    result += number
  end
  print result
end
```

I receive this: `0033814141423`, but I expect `23`, as it's the sum of `3`, `5`, `6`, `9`.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `print` statement is inside the loop. It should be moved outside.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
result = 0
numbers.each do |number|
  if number % 3 == 0 or number % 5 == 0
    result += number
  end
end
print result
```

A proper indentation will also help you to catch these errors. Moreover, you should use `p` to print out an information, not `print`.

With `p` each output would have been done on a new line. That would probably be an hint to understand the issue.

This is also a possible alternative using `Enumerable#inject` with an accumulator.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
numbers.inject(0) do |acc, number|
  acc + case
    when number % 3 == 0 then number
    when number % 5 == 0 then number
    else 0
  end
end
```

And a more compact form

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
numbers.lazy.select { |n| n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 }.inject(:+)
```

Comment: Or `puts` which is `print` with newline. `p x` is like `puts x.inspect`.

Comment: Ahh, I see, the thing that got me confused was the fact that I didn't know if statements must have end, althought it is rather obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Array#select` method.

```
result = 0
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].select{|i| i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0}.each do |num|
  result += num
end
```

or more shortly with `inject`.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].select{|i| i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0}.inject(:+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I did was something like this:

```
(1...10).to_a.select{|i| i%3==0 or i%5==0}.sum
```